# Move four wheels on a curved path

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm researching the movement of four wheels on a curved track. The image below is of a stairlift.

[image]

As it is known, the four moving wheels are in a fixed position relative to each other. This structure can follow a direct and curved path. but how?

As shown below, this should not be possible on a curved path. When two wheels are tangential to the direction of track, the other two wheels are in the inappropriate position and it is not possible to move.

[image]

But according to the first picture, in practice this is possible. But I do not know how

by the way as below image shows the rollers are not conical
[image]

Comment: Those wheels are probably conical like on a train. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3n5I-s4AfQ).

Comment: @JohnDouma no it does not seem so

Comment: The lines on the sides of those wheels don't look parallel to me. Have you tried measuring the diameter of both ends?